# How to use/install Language Model of StanfordCoreNLP ? (english-full, english-kbp)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am planning to use StanfordCoreNLP for my exercise on sentiment analysis.

Can anyone let me know the steps to install / use stanfordcorenlp models - english-full and english-kbp ?

i have downloaded stanfordcorenlp from their site. 
filename is: stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip

now i want to use their other english models like english-full and english-kbp.

If anyone can let me know steps to add above mentioned two models ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. navigate to directory with stanfordcorenlp
2. unzip into desired directory
3. `cd <path to stanfordcorenlp>/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/`
4. Start the Stanford CoreNLP server from terminal. This will start a StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at port 9000.

   java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -annotators
   "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment" -port 9000 -timeout 30000
5. In your python file run `pip install stanfordcorenlp` to install the stanfordcorenlp package

   ```
    from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
    import json 
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost', port=9000, timeout=30000)
   ```
6. Define properties. define kbp in annotators

   ```
    props = {'annotators': 'pos,lemma,kbp','outputFormat': 'json'}
    sentence = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the fence'
    parsed_str = nlp.annotate(sentence, properties=props)
    parsed_dict = json.loads(parsed_str)
    print(parsed_dict)
   ```

Note:first time running kbp or any new language model, there will be a delay, however, after the first run it should run much quicker